# Is there a plugin or framework that converts java web app war to maven war (pom.xml and mvn install command)?

Tags: java, maven, war

Is there a plugin or framework that converts a java web application (war) into a maven project (pom.xml and mvn install command jar)? Thanks

EDIT An alpha java program that converts a jar's list into a maven project (pom.xml and mvn install command jar) is:
https://github.com/sunrelax/jar2mvn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groupId for the artifacts is not even in the manifests within the jars in the lib folder so the research to fit version+groupId is quite complex.
Also, the way the package is generated (war-plugin) and the specific folders the original files are located can't be deducted.
ONLY in the case you decide to pass all the standards, and keep your own repository (with your own groupIds), maybe will be possible to auto-assign from jars version own-generated-groupId... but it's not worth it, later it would be difficult to maintain.
Better, and talking about third part libraries, take the jars one by one and hopefully you will have the version in the manifest and locate them in public repositories.